# Error while using idref in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am getting the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.mycompany.springdemo.Point' for property 'point0'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.mycompany.springdemo.Point] for property 'point0': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

my spring configuration file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-      beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="com.mycompany.springdemo.Triangle">
        <property name="point0">
            <idref bean = "point01"/>
        </property>
        <property name="point1">
            <bean class="com.mycompany.springdemo.Point">
                <property name="x" value="20"/>
                <property name="y" value="0"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="point2">
            <bean class="com.mycompany.springdemo.Point">
                <property name="x" value="0"/>
                <property name="y" value="20"/>
           </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="point01" class="com.mycompany.springdemo.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0"/>
        <property name="y" value="0"/>
    </bean>  

</beans>
```

If i use 'ref' to initialize point0 then it works fine, but it errors for 'idref'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring IDREF usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607142/spring-idref-usage)

Comment: Any reason you are using Spring 2? If you are trying to learn Spring you should probably not be relying on a very old and (probably) unsupported version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BeanInstantiationException:Cannot convert type from java.lang.String to required type --- idref tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234568/beaninstantiationexceptioncannot-convert-type-from-java-lang-string-to-required)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<property name="point0">
            <idref bean = "point01"/>
</property>
```

use this:

```
<property name="point0" ref="point01" />
```

[and read the documentation about idref](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-idref-element)